# Is this the correct way to use LINQ Group By?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have two tables. Cars and Dealers. Each car has a dealerID associated with it. Each dealer has a state attribute.  I need to write a query that will tell me how many cars there are per state in the database. I have not had to use group by yet but I think this is what it is used for.  This is as far as i got before i realized i needed help.

```
        var query = (from c in _db.Cars
                     join d in _db.Dealers on c.DealerID equals d.DealerID
                     where c.Active == true
                     group c by d.State);
```

Goal is to have a listview list each state with the total cars per state as the end results.

Comment: Is your query OK? Looks like it works. What is the type of `State`?

Comment: Try it on a simple dataset where you can easily check if it's returning the correct results.

Comment: @KingKing I am not able to select the state and return the count of the cars from it. As far as i know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me help by writing it in extensions method:

```
var query = 
_db.Cars
.Join
(
    _db.Dealers,
    c=>c.DealerID,
    d=>d.DealerID,
    (car,dealer)=>new {car,dealer}
)
.Where
(
    x=>x.car.Active//no reason to check with == true if this is boolean
)
.GroupBy
(
    x=>x.dealer.State
)
.Select
(
    x=>new 
    {
        State = x.Key,
        Cars = x.Count()
    }
);
```